# Unable to show a map on the emulator

Tags: android

I use map api v2.

On Android 6.0 on device and emulator when start Map , it's ask me about permission. I click "allow" on device and  map is show. But on emulator show this:

[image: map]

Why not show map on emulator?

Comment: Usually this means your keys are are wrong

Comment: I think your emulator doesn't have play services or it is unable to fetch a location.

Comment: just check your API key and check if the project on the Console has GoogleMaps enabled.
copy paste your API key in project

Comment: On device map work fine. But on emulator the same application not show map.

Answer (score 0):

it has few options, 
1. you do not have internet or internet access
2. your "google map service/google services" are not enabled.
3. as far as i know it puts you on the map somewhere.but you can go to ADB and put a specific location to the emulator that might help.